# What's another way to say "Is this on your horizon?"

Tags: idioms

What's another way to say, 
"Is X on your agenda?" or
"Is X on your horizon?"

Comment: Basically, you're asking if X is being considered. There are many ways to say this, and it would help if you could narrow it down a bit. Is it work related? Written or spoken? Is politeness a factor? What is the setting? The more you can narrow down your request, the more likely you are to get the answer you desire.

Answer (score 2):

- "Are you tracking X?"
- "Is X on your radar?"
- "Do you have X under control?
- "Is X a loose end?"
- "Do your plans include X?"